# SELinux on CentOS7-based LXC?

Tags: centos, selinux, lxc, proxmox

Is there any way to enable SELinux on LXC-based container using [proxmox](/questions/tagged/proxmox) 4.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "enabled" you mean to have a full fledged SELinux policy *within* the container, the answer is no.

Of course the host where the containers are deployed can have SELinux enforced, and the processes within the container can be confined as well.
This confinement operates from the host server point of view.

There is support for [sVirt](http://selinuxproject.org/page/SVirt) MCS/MLS confinement for [libvirt managed LXC containers](https://major.io/2014/04/21/launch-secure-lxc-containers-on-fedora-20-using-selinux-and-svirt/) (as well as docker based containers).